# Where to get a list of boost libraries included into VS2010 as part of STD?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, boost, std

Where to get a list of boost libraries included into VS2010 as part of STD?

Comment: To clarify: no Boost libraries are distributed with Visual Studio. Some libraries from Boost were incorporated into the C++ TR1 and C++0x specifications (sometimes with changes), and many of these libraries that have been standardized or are in the process of being standardized are shipped with Visual Studio. The implementations of the libraries shipped with Visual Studio are probably not the same as those of the libraries found in Boost (I honestly don't know, but I would be _very_ surprised if they were), but they should conform to the TR1 and C++0x specifications.

Comment: http://www.dinkumware.com/tr1.aspx - "This component is based largely on contributions made to the Boost library" (talking about the TR1 parts that came from Boost, as opposed to the C99 component or TF1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx

Strictly speaking these are the TR1 headers that are included with VS2010, I believe some of the types were renamed from their boost counterparts.

---

```
<array>
```

> Defines the container template class array and several supporting templates.

---

```
<functional> (TR1)
```

> Defines several templates that help construct function objects, which are objects of a type that defines operator(). A function object can be a function pointer, but more typically, the object is used to store additional information that can be accessed during a function call.

---

```
<memory> (TR1)
```

> Defines a class, an operator, and several templates that help allocate and free objects.

---

```
<random>
```

> Defines many random number generators.

---

```
<regex>
```

> Defines a template class to parse regular expressions, and several template classes and functions to search text for matches to a regular expression object.

```
<tuple>
```

> Defines a template tuple Class whose instances hold objects of varying types.

---

```
<type_traits>
```

> Defines templates that provide compile-time constants that give information about the properties of their type arguments.

---

```
<unordered_map>
```

> Defines the container template classes unordered_map and unordered_multimap and their supporting templates.

---

```
<unordered_set>
```

> Defines the container template classes unordered_multiset and unordered_set and their supporting templates.

---

```
<utility> (TR1)
```

> Defines several general templates that can be used throughout the Standard Template Library.

Comment: Please add newlines to your descriptions.

Comment: @Kabumbus - VS 2010 doesn't have `thread`, but if you need it, you can use `boost::thread`. Same with graph.

Comment: Yes but yo have to compile boost first... And on EEEPC it takes more than 4 hovers...  but any way at least regexp is there=)